# Problem with vertical alignment in tabular environment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, boxes

I'm having a few issues with vertically aligning table elements. There seems to be too much space either above or below the text or image. Is this to do with the `fbox` environment? I want both the image and text to be centered vertically in each table cell.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{
    \begin{center}
    \fbox{
    \parbox{0.8\linewidth}{
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{ c m{4.5in} }
            \includegraphics[height=0.3in]{./myfig} & {#1}
            \end{tabular} 
        \end{center}
        }
     }
    \end{center}
}


\begin{document}

\mybox{hello}

\mybox{hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** Following Gonzalo Medina's suggestion, I get:
[image]
and there is no difference between `center` and `centering`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `m{length}` column type for the first column:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{
    \begin{center}
    \fbox{%
    \parbox{0.8\linewidth}{%
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{m{0.3in}m{4.5in} }
            \includegraphics[height=0.3in]{example-image-a} & #1
            \end{tabular} 
        \end{center}
        }
     }
    \end{center}%
}


\begin{document}

\mybox{hello}

\mybox{hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello}


\end{document}
```

[image]

I wasn't sure if some of the blank spaces at end of lines were intentional or not; I commented them out. Also take into account that `center` adds some vertical spacing so perhaps you could consider using `\centering` instead.

As an alternative, I'd like to propose the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package to easily produce your box; you can even customize it even further:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand\mybox[1]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
      sidebyside,
      lefthand width=.3in,
      colback=white,
      outer arc=0pt,
      arc=0pt.
      colframe=black,
      boxrule=0.4pt,
      segmentation engine=empty
    ]
    \includegraphics[width=.3in]{example-image-a}
    \tcblower
    #1
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}

\mybox{hello}

\mybox{hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `valign` macro from the `adjustbox` package in

```
\includegraphics[valign=c,height=0.3in]{example-image-a}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  %% export is needed
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{%
    \begin{center}
    \fbox{%
    \parbox{0.8\linewidth}{%
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{ c m{0.75\linewidth} }
            \includegraphics[valign=c,height=0.3in]{example-image-a} & #1
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
        }%
     }%
    \end{center}
}


\begin{document}

\mybox{hello}

\mybox{hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello}


\end{document}
```

[image]